React Native with Expo for Web and Mobile Devices
I am thinking about doing an App that should be practically the same or very similar for Web and iOS/Android.
After investigating a bit, I've found that maybe the best fit for this would be using React Native.
Is it a good idea to create it with Expo?
If that's the case, can I do the Build to deploy the web version and the mobile version with the same project / code? I don't understand completely how is it working
Thanks,
                                          .


In order to run the application you developed with React Native as both a website and a mobile application, using EXPO, the framework of React Native, would be the right decision for your goal.
Terminal Installation:
Use the 'npx create-expo-app' command to create a new Expo project.
Run 'npx create-expo-app --template' to see a list of available templates.
Optionally, you can select a "Blank" or "Navigation" project from the templates, and choose "TypeScript" as the programming language.
Run:
The 'yarn' command installs the necessary modules in the project.
Start the Expo server with the 'expo start' command.
Select the platform to run on by using the corresponding button: 'i' for iOS, 'a' for Android, 'w' for Web.
For detailed installation and review, refer to the Expo documentation.
Project Output Transactions:
Creating a Build File:
The build file is created with the 'expo build:web' command. The build files are located in the web-build folder within the module directory.
While performing build or run operations in Expo Web projects, you may encounter the error: 'Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported'.
Solution Processes:
Run the command 'export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider' before performing build or run operations.

I wrote a quite detailed article on how React Native and Expo relate to each other, and if it is worth using React Native without Expo.
TLDR; it does not.
You  are almost always better off using Expo, even the React Native team recommends that.
For the longer, comprehensive answer, read my blog post.
